# Finding rows that match with an specific character

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a dataset that contains information about some online purchases made by customer, and I need to create a list of customers if their last name starts with a capital Z.

The dataset looks like this:

[image]

So far this is what I have achieved:

```
# Extracting last name from a sorted list of customers
customers_lastname = str([x.split(" ")[-1] for x in customers_sorted])

# Creating a list of customers that his last names starts with Z using list comprehension

lastname_z = [customer for customer in customers_sorted if customers_lastname[-1].startswith('Z')]
```

But after printing the results, I'm only getting an empty list : `[]`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you doing `customers_lastname = str(...)`? That will convert the list to a string...

Comment: BTW, I think you can do it with a single list comprehension: `lastname_z = [customer for customer in customers_sorted if customer.split(" ")[-1].startswith('Z')]`

Comment: Check the answer from @DaniMesejo above. Your code doesn't make sense. When you convert customers_lastname list into string type, its last character always is ]. So  the condition is False.

Comment: Thanks for your support, Im newbie in Python and don't have very clear a lot of concepts. One day at a time! (y)